# Resource linking fails on lStar with error

Tags: android

I'm working on a android Native application. My Android builds began to fail without any changes.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':etndoorcontrol:processHesuan_faceDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\xqf\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fe7b90aa462d9a2e04dd8216aa450a51\res\values\values.xml:2422:5-2449:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

  error: failed linking references.
```

Then I tried 2 solutions

```
//soultion 1.
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // Java language implementation
        force "androidx.core:core:1.6.0"
        // Kotlin
        force "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"

    }
}
```

After I add this to app/build.gradle, the app can build correct.but after I install the apk and run .there is a new problem.

```
java stacktrace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
    at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:2551)
    at java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:169)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:193)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findUsingReflectionInSingleClass(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:163)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findUsingInfo(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:88)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:64)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:140)
    at com.yarward.a10doorcontrol.homepage.HomePageActivity.initFields(HomePageActivity.java:334)
    at com.yarward.base.mvp.view.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:82)
    at com.yarward.a10doorcontrol.homepage.HomePageActivity.onCreate(HomePageActivity.java:257)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6709)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2736)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1487)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6157)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:53)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/view/MenuHost;
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:53)
    at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:2551)
    at java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:169)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:193)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1812)
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findUsingReflectionInSingleClass(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:154)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.view.MenuHost" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.yarward.hesuanface-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.yarward.hesuanface-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.yarward.hesuanface-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 28 more
```

After this, I tried the other solution, as below:

```
ext{
  androidX = 1.6.0
}
```

but this is not working for me.

Comment: `lStar` is a system attribute that's new as of API level 31, but your current build tools aren't new enough to know about it. To update those, all you need to do is change the `compileSdkVersion` to 31.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[axel8888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3308577/axel8888) thank your sir, yes, I have solved this problem. yes, you are right , when I try solution one again

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // Java language implementation
        force "androidx.core:core:1.6.0"
        // Kotlin
        force "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"

    }
}
```

and as you  the problem is now in

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0-alpha
```

so I checked the gradle dependencies, yes , even I used

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1
```

but my project shows the version is 1.4.0-alpha. here is my solution

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            
            if (requested.group == "androidx.appcompat") {
                if (requested.name == "appcompat") {
                    details.useVersion "1.3.1"
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

and it worked, now my project can build and run correctly, thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Obveiously the problem is now in androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0-alpha. If your UI use Toolbar, you will get the MenuHost not found crash.BUT, evenif I use resolutionStrategy to force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1', dependency still make it toandroidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.4.0-beta01}

It still confuse me a lot.

SOLVED -- someone write a update code for appcompat before... now it can force to 1.3.1 and solve the problem

Comment: how to solved ? could you post the link or tell me how, please

Comment: just like your solution, other contributer write something other before but at first I didn't discover that...

Answer (score 0):

change
implementation **'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'**
to
implementation **'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'**

that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
```

was causing the problem, going back to 1.3.1 worked.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

ill update once I get an official solution.